# Confirming Source Is From QR Code Scan

Tags: authentication, mobile, qr-code

I have this project where I need to know if a visitor legitimately arrived from a QR code. Document.referrer value from a QR code shows blank. I have looked at some answers suggesting to put parameter in the query string (e.g. `?source=qr`), but anyone could easily add the parameter into the URL and my code would believe it is from a QR code (e.g. `www.project.com/check.page?source=qr`) . I have thought of adding codes to make sure it is from a mobile phone / tablet as secondary way to authenticate but many browsers have add-ons to fool websites.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“but many browsers have add-ons to fool websites”_ – so what? Why would you _care_ how a request is made? And no, you can of course _not_ make sure a request came “from” a QR code, since that “from” does not exist. The QR code is just a way of giving someone an URL – _requesting_ that URL is done completely separately from that.

Comment: I care how a request is made because I like to know what location the visitor came from. Then base on where that person came from, it would redirect to the right page. I know QR code could give someone an URL.

Comment: So you are using different QR codes for different (physical) locations, and redirecting the user to a page presenting data according to that location? Well _then_ why would you care if the user “fakes” this, as it would just mean he would not get presented with the “right” data …?

Comment: not only would he get the wrong data, the person would also see information for different location.

Comment: So what? If someone chose to input a “wrong” URL _deliberately_, what does that matter to you?

Comment: wouldn't scanning the code bring them to the right URL? On top of that, parameter for qr code location would redirect them to the right page. Wrong parameter would bring them a 404 page

Comment: Yes. So now you are finally acknowledging that there _is_ no real problem here if the user just scans the QR code as intended …?

Comment: Look, I'm not sure if the edited title from another user confused you. What i'm trying to do is when someone scans the QR Code, I would know it is indeed the QR code brought them there and that's why I want to check if there's a way to see if the referrer is from QR code. Different information are provided to the user base on the location where the QR code was scanned. Now, if there is a way to check that the person came directly from a different source, then the scripts could say 'hey this is not from a qr code scan', redirect somewhere else.

Comment: _“I would know it is indeed the QR code brought them there ”_ – that’s not possible. Period. _“to see if the referrer is from QR code”_ – there _is_ no referrer for cases like this. The referrer holds the address of another web page where a link to the current page has been clicked. No other web page = no referrer.

Comment: i know that. that's why i wrote "Document.referrer value from a QR code shows blank."

Comment: So what’s there to discuss if you already knew that, and refuse what actually _is_ technically possible (with rather bogus arguments against it)?

Comment: this is why i ask for suggestions to see if there are any methods.

Comment: No, there are none – because your assumption that there was any “from” in this case is already false.

Comment: doesn't hurt to ask for suggestions. you wasted alot of minutes arguing when you could've just said "no, there are none"

Comment: I said that straight away. After that I only wanted to figure out what _problem_ you actually want to solve here, because there seems to be absolutely none. Again: If the user manipulates anything in a given URL and as a result gets “wrong” data – then that’s their problem and not yours …

Comment: The problem is I want to find out if the person legitimately came from a QR code scan. It's not so much that they would see the wrong data, it's more about target regions have information for them and not for others. QR codes are presented at different regions, and only those people that scan can see information for their area.

Comment: So the problem is not specific to QR codes at all – it is the same problem for anyone who requests that URL, no matter _how_ they came upon it.

Comment: Using the HTML5 Geolocation API would be one way of checking if the user is actually near or around where you think they are based upon the location-specific URL. (Of course also not “secure”.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I am explaining this correctly or what. The problem: There are different QR codes for regions. When a person scans it, it brings them to a page with information. That information is for people who scanned the QR code and no one else. I like to know if there are ways to detect if the person came from a QR code scan, if it is then allow them to go to that information page, if not, don't allow them.

Comment: _“That information is for people who scanned the QR code and no one else.”_ – that’s basically the same as if you said, _“calling me should only be possible for people who read my phone number on the wall of the third stall in the restroom of that bar where I scrawled it on last night, and for no-one else.”_ – it should be pretty obvious that there’s _multiple_ other ways for people to get your number, and that there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: dude, i don't know what's up with this attitude. I asked suggestions nicely, and you keep giving me this attitude. I acknowledge it is not possible, but asked for suggestions. You keep asking me different questions on every comment or make some sarcastic comment.

Comment: There _is_ nothing to suggest here, because you are asking to verify something that _is not verifiable_ by its very nature. And I only want to make you understand that.

Comment: your above comment is your best answer in this discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution for you is creating your regional QR Codes pointing to:

```
Region 1)  http://example.com/?qr=f61060194c9c6763bb63385782aa216f
Region 2)  http://example.com/?qr=731417b947aa548528344fab8e0f29b6
Region 3)  http://example.com/?qr=df189e7f7c8b89edd05ccc6aec36c36d
```

if the value of the parameter *qr* is **anything** other than *f61060194c9c6763bb63385782aa216f*, *731417b947aa548528344fab8e0f29b6* or *df189e7f7c8b89edd05ccc6aec36c36d*, then you can ignore it and assume the user didn't come from any QR Code.

Of course, any user can remove the *source* parameter. But at least he can't add a valid one, unless he really had access to the code.

Comment: Thanks @Jorge it gives me the idea of putting a long value for qr variable which should be harder for anyone to guess for different location values

Answer (score 0):

> ...but anyone could easily add the parameter into the URL and my code would believe it is from a QR code

Well, anyone could also scan the QR code, view the link, and remove the `source=qr` from it.

Data collection is *never* 100% reliable. Users can change their browser's user agent, inject cookies with some strange values, open your page through a proxy server, and so on.

You could [create your own device](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000037.html) or App for scanning the QR-code. If you read the post I've linked, you will see that this is a waste of time and resources.

So, what is left is to make a solution which will work for *most* of the users. Appending a `source=qr` parameter to your URL seems to be the simplest solution. You could also link to an entirely different domain and redirect the request, so it would be more fraud-safe. But it will *never* be 100% accurate.

Comment: thanks @Uooo ... there would be page to check parameters to see where the QR code was scanned then redirect to a different page based on the location of the QR code.